# How to map users to flask session file in server?

Tags: flask, session, flask-session

I still use the flask session manager for users. My config is like this:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "mySecretKey"
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
```

Whenever a user logs in a flask session file is created in the folder `app\flask_session`. It will be random alphanumeric file name, like `0609ece61011830ef9b6547217b9abd6`.

the session file contains the email of the user. What I want to do is to delete a flask session file when a user resets their password, for security reasons. Like the user might have logged in to 5 devices and as the sessions don't expire the user gets to use the account on all 5 devices. But when the user changes the password, I need to delete all these 5 sessions which match the email id so that the user gets logged out on all the devices.

I am ready to loop through each session file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pickle` package for that. Here is an example how to parse one of the session files:

```
import pickle
with open("sessions_dir/701dc705b498a6ee20475e5fcbcbdf99", "rb") as e:
    time = pickle.load(e)
    data = pickle.load(e)
    print(time)
    print(data)
```

You will need to get the email id from the `data` and act accordingly.